# is it possible to declare these bindings with RabbitListener?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-amqp

given this code

```
    @Bean
    open fun exchange(): TopicExchange {
        return TopicExchange("amq.topic")
    }
```

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = [Amqp.BODY_WEIGHT_NEW])
    open fun record(entity: Collection<BodyWeight>) {
        log.trace("saving: {}", entity)
    }

    @Bean
    open fun weight(): Queue {
        return Queue(Amqp.BODY_WEIGHT_NEW)
    }

    @Bean
    open fun bindWeight(): Binding {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(weight()).to(exchange).with(Amqp.BODY_WEIGHT_NEW)
    }
```

is it possible to reduce my @Bean declarations using `@RabbitListener`? I know I can list the queue as a queue to declare, but I'm not sure on what the bindings would look like.

tried this

```
    @RabbitListener(bindings = [QueueBinding(value = Queue(Amqp.BODY_WEIGHT_NEW), exchange = Exchange("amqp.topic"))])
```

but it doesn't seem to bind to the exchange in the same way, as my tests aren't passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the routing key to the `@QueueBinding`...

```
key = Amqp.BODY_WEIGHT_NEW
```

(that's what the `with` clause on the `BindingBuilder` does).

**EDIT**

Works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class So55928905Application {

    @RabbitListener(bindings = [QueueBinding(value = Queue("foo"), 
                                  exchange = Exchange("amqp.topic"), 
                                  key = ["foo"])])
    fun `in`(`in`: String) {

    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(So55928905Application::class.java, *args)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

The problem is your exchange name MQTT publishes to the standard `amq.topic` not `amqp.topic`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class So55928905Application {

    @RabbitListener(bindings = [QueueBinding(value = Queue("foo"),
                        exchange = Exchange(name = "amq.topic", type = "topic"),
                        key = ["foo"])])
    fun listen(string: String) {
        println(string)
    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(So55928905Application::class.java, *args)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tested it (again) with Java and it works fine - I'll try Kotlin to see if that's the issue.

Comment: most likely it has something to do with the mqtt aspect (that I didn't mention because I didn't think it would be relevant) that or the fact that I have many of these doing the old way and have only converted one...

Comment: If you can provide more information about this "mqtt aspect", I can take a look to see if there is something we can do.

Comment: well the short of it is I publish via mqtt https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html and then am listening on amqp. I can try to provide more info later, but the bindings I've shown have been working though that's more likely dumb luck than understanding.

Comment: The problem is your exchange name - see my second edit.